# Author of story that I think was called "the Grantha Incident"

Tags: story-identification, first-contact

I'm trying to remember the author of a first contact story from the 50s or 60s.  I think it was called "The Grantha Incident" but can't turn up anything with that title.  In the story, a spaceship breaks down near an isolated farmhouse.  The farm couple meet the aliens and find they can understand them even though they don't speak the same language -- they realize that their engine has a problem; the farmer helps the male alien fix it while the farm wife takes the female alien into the kitchen to warm the alien baby's bottle.  Then the guys have fixed the engine & the aliens go on their way.  Others saw the ship land, and reporters soon show up.  The farmer starts to explain that it was just a little mechanical trouble and they sent these nice people on their way, but his wife, who is very lonely on their isolated farm, retells the visit so that it fits the common "alien visitation" scenario so that people will come and visit them.

My first two thoughts for authors were Shirley Jackson and then Avram Davidson, but I can't find it in either of their bibliographies.  I may have the title wrong as well.

Comment: It wasn't "[The Roswell Incident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roswell_UFO_incident)"?

Comment: For future reference, here's how you could have found the title of that story: (1) visit the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi); (2) select "Fiction Titles" from the "Search the database" dropdown menu over on the left side; (3) type "grantha" in the search box; (4) click on "Go".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "*Grantha Incident*" is mentioned in the story "[The Grantha Sighting](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56767)" (collected in [Or All the Seas with Oysters](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?448828)) By Avram Davidson.

[image]

You can read an excerpt [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=M_S1dYG7WnoC&pg=PT22&lpg=PT22&dq=%22Grantha%20Incident%22&source=bl&ots=CMGTfzQmGl&sig=YxmFrc7Yzjtz1ITbJe-2G-MSEic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UrPBVLXGK8vxUv2lgfgB&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Grantha%20Incident%22&f=false)

Answer (score 8):

[The Grantha Sighting](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56767) by Avram Davidson indeed. First published in 1958.

According the isfdb.org listing, it was collected in **Or All the Seas with Oysters**, among other works.

Here's a radio drama version of it:

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!  My pulp copy of Or All the Seas with Oysters just disintegrated a couple of years ago.  I'll have to find another copy.